# How Much Current Draw From Speakers/Amplifier?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, current, amplifier, audio

So I plan on using the VS1053 Codec connected to a class D Amp (2 x 2.8W channel) with two 3W 4 Ohm speakers. If I supply 5V to this setup, what would the current draw be at full use?

Codec: https://www.adafruit.com/products/1381 
Amp: https://www.adafruit.com/products/1712 
Speakers: https://www.adafruit.com/products/1669

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs the efficiency is reasonably high, I believe 89% for 8Ω is mentioned.

If you want to be able to drive the speakers at full power continuously:

Total power [Watt] = number of channels × power per channel

P = 2 × 2.8 = 5.6 W

Supply current drawn for the speakers alone would be:

Current [Ampère] = Power [Watt] / Voltage[Volt]

I = P / V = 5.6 / 5 = 1.12 A

Accounting for efficiency, you are looking at 1.12 / 0.89 = 1.26A. This is with 8Ω load, efficiency with a 4Ω load will be worse.

The [datasheet for the amp](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa2016d2.pdf) states another 5.5 mA supply current.

The [datasheet for the codec](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/vs1053.pdf) lists power draw of up to 60 mA.

Total current draw would be at least 1.35A at full load.

However there are quite a few assumptions here and you really want some headroom for unforeseen things. Maybe you want to add a indicator LED? I did not account for an SD card or another microcontroller to control things. In practice you mustn't aim for a power supply that can't do *at least* 1.5A and I'd probably pick a **2A power supply** as it is good practice to not push a power supply to its spec'd limits.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply.
You cannot simply develiver full power (2.8W) into 8 Ohm speaker by using 5V power supply. So the answer given by jippie is wrong, the assumption is wrong.
I suggest you to read this answer by jonk "[Max Voltage for Speaker of Given Power Rating](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/370758/max-voltage-for-speaker-of-given-power-rating)"

So you use class D amp with BTL connection, the maximum power you can deliver to 8 Ohm speaker is (5/1.41)^2/8 = 1.57W, of course you should also count loss on amp.
You can also see the similar result from amp datasheet:

1.7 W/Ch Into 8 Ω at 5 V (10% THD+N)

2.8 W/Ch Into 4 Ω at 5 V (10% THD+N)

So you can only develiver 2.8W full power to ***4 Ohm speaker at 5V***.

So I will use this data from datasheet to be used as "full use" to calculate current draw:

THD+N = 10%, VDD = 5 V, RL = 8 Ω    1.72W

For efficiency at 90%, the current draw by speaker amp Iamp = 1.72/0.9/5 = 382mA